# python regular expression to match dots and brackets

Tags: python, regex, special-characters

I am trying to write a regex to delete the below patterns from text file:

```
[...] (one or more dots in between [] )
[. . . .] (one or more dots between [] with space in them)
```

I tried things like this `[^A-Za-z]\[.*\]` however it matched all the words in between them. 
eg for `this is [...] what you want to keep. [....] [. . . ] [ . ..]and [this]` It matched from the first [ to the last ]. Could someone please help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below regex.

```
\[(\s*\.\s*)*\]
```

You need to escape `.` as it represents any character in regex terms, so the correct usage is `\.`.

Comment: You can reduce your expression to `\[[ .]+\]` in order to be closer to the question (right now, your expression matches across line breaks and empty brackets `[]`, too) and to increase performance a little.